# Deleting Duplicate Row Combinations in a given Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a dataset of about `160 000` entries, they are computer generated and over the years mistakes happened.

Lets say the Table has the following columns:

```
- EntryID (auto int)
- FruitNumber
- JuiceNumber
- CandyNumber
- Date
```

Now the important thing is each combination of `FruitNumber, JuiceNumber,CandyNumber` is Unique when the time between them is less than 12 Months.

That means every exact combination of these can only exist once in 12 months. Now I need to get this dataset migrated into a new data model and for this I need to delete duplicate records (but keep 1 of them), I tried around alot with Queries but wasn´t able to find a solution.

Comment: If there are two same records within 12 months, should we keep the earlier one?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis The later one

Comment: Which sql server version are you using? Some advanced window functions may come in handy. Also, another example: Let's say you had for the same "key" dates 10 Jan 2019,11 Jan 2018,12 Jan 17, Should we then only keep the first and the third one?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis 14.0.1000 (thats 2017 i think)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis In theory this shouldnt happen because the computer based errors dont have such a huge timespan, but if that happens then yes in this case only first and third one

Comment: I am sorry, I have misunderstand the question, therefore my answer is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use cte:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT 
  ft.EntryID
, ft.FruitNumber
, ft.JuiceNumber
, ft.CandyNumber
, ft.Date
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.FruitNumber, ft.JuiceNumber, ft.CandyNumber 
     ORDER BY ft.FruitNumber) RN
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ft.FruitNumber, ft.JuiceNumber, ft.CandyNumber) 
     AS Partitionid
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ft.FruitNumber, ft.JuiceNumber, ft.CandyNumber 
     ORDER BY ft.FruitNumber) as PartitionCNT
FROM FooTable ft
)

SELECT 
t1.* 
, DATEDIFF(DAY, t.Date, t1.Date) DATEDiff
FROM 
cte t 
INNER JOIN cte t1 
    ON t1.FruitNumber = t.FruitNumber
        AND  t1.JuiceNumber = t.JuiceNumber
        AND  t1.CandyNumber = t.CandyNumber
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t.Date, t1.Date)>= 365
WHERE t.PartitionCNT > 1
```

And the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE FooTable
(
    EntryID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FruitNumber INT,
    JuiceNumber INT,
    CandyNumber INT,
    [Date] DATETIME
);*/


INSERT INTO FooTable
VALUES
(1, 2, 3 , '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1, 2, 3 , '2020-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
(4, 5, 6 , '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
(7, 8, 9 , '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
(10, 11, 12 , '2018-03-20 00:00:00.000'),
(13, 14, 15 , '2018-03-20 00:00:00.000'),
(16, 17, 18 , '2017-03-09 00:00:00.000'),
(16, 17, 18 , '2017-02-09 00:00:00.000'),
(22, 23, 34 , '2017-02-12 00:00:00.000'),
(22, 23, 34 , '2017-02-12 00:00:00.000');
```

And OUTPUT:

```
EntryID FruitNumber JuiceNumber CandyNumber
   2           1           2          3
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, could you explain it a bit more i have trouble understanding its result

Comment: Hey thanks, but this only brings me the records happening on the same date not in a date range of 12 months or?

Answer (score 0):

If the errors are merely occasional, then this is likely to work:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by FruitNumber, JuiceNumber, CandyNumber) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is null or prev_date < dateadd(year, -1, date);
```

This is not a general solution -- although you can run this query multiple times.  In particular, this only works if you have at most one duplicate during a year.

Unfortunately, the general solution requires recursive CTEs.  For instance, if you have a record every month, it is tricky to figure out how to keep the "january" records.